# Why does cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer segfault when I change my cuda kernel?

Tags: linux, opengl, ubuntu, cuda, segmentation-fault

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 with cuda toolkit 6.5, nvidia driver version 340.29. My application registers a pixel buffer from openGL and writes an image to the buffer every loop, copies the PBO to a texture using glTexSubImage2D, and draws the texture. This all works properly until I change my image-generation kernel, then I gdb reports a segmentation fault in cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer. My guess is this is a bug, because the cuda kernel is completely unrelated to cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer, which is called before any processing.

Makefile

```
CUDA=nvcc
CPP=g++

OUT=out

INC=-I/usr/local/cuda-6.5/include

LINK=-lcudart -lglfw -lGLEW -lGL

FLAGS=-std=gnu++11
CUFLAGS=-std=c++11

all: main.cu GLdisplay.cu
    $(CUDA) main.cu GLdisplay.cu -o $(OUT) $(CUFLAGS) $(INC) $(LINK)

clean:
    rm ./$(OUT)

add:
    git add -A
    git status
```

main.cu

```
#define  GLEW_STATIC

// C++ headers
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

// openGL headers
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

// CUDA headers
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda_gl_interop.h>

#include "GLdisplay.h"

#define WINDOW_WIDTH  640
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT 480

#define TEX_WIDTH     1920
#define TEX_HEIGHT    1080

using std::cout;
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::ifstream;

GLFWwindow* window;
GLuint vao, vbo, pbo;
GLuint vtx, frg, shaders;
GLuint tex;

uint8_t* cudaPBOptr;
size_t cudaPBOsize;

cudaGraphicsResource_t cuGfxPBO;

string loadTxtFileAsString( string filename )
{
    string source;
    string buf = "";
    ifstream file( filename, std::ios::in );

    while( file.good( ) )
    {
        std::getline( file, buf );
        source.append( buf + "\n" );
    }

    file.close( );

    return source;
}

void shaderCompileCheck( void )
{
    GLint status;

    // vertex
    glGetShaderiv( vtx, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );

    if( GL_TRUE != status )
    {
        char buffer[ 512 ];
        glGetShaderInfoLog( vtx, 512, NULL, buffer );
        cerr << "vtx err | " << buffer << endl;
    }

    // fragment
    glGetShaderiv( frg, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );

    if( GL_TRUE != status )
    {
        char buffer[ 512 ];
        glGetShaderInfoLog( frg, 512, NULL, buffer );
        cerr << "frg err | " << buffer << endl;
    }
}

// added exit on !cudaSuccess
#define cudaErr(err) cudaError( err, __FILE__, __LINE__ )
inline void cudaError( cudaError_t err, const char* file, uint32_t line, bool abort=true )
{
    if( cudaSuccess != err )
    {
        cerr << "[" << file << ":" << line << "] ";
        cerr << cudaGetErrorName( err ) << endl; // print the name instead of description
        if( abort ) exit( err );
    }
}

// added GL error checking
#define glErr( ) glError( glGetError( ), __FILE__, __LINE__ )
inline void glError( GLenum err, const char* file, uint32_t line, bool abort=false )
{
    if( GL_NO_ERROR != err )
    {
        cerr << "[" << file << ":" << line << "] ";
        cerr << glewGetErrorString( err ) << endl;
        if( abort ) exit( err );
    }
}

// main function
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    string vString = loadTxtFileAsString( "vert.glsl" );
    string fString = loadTxtFileAsString( "frag.glsl" );

    const GLchar* vtxSource = vString.c_str( );
    const GLchar* frgSource = fString.c_str( );

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

    glfwInit( );

    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3 );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2 );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE );

    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE );

    window = glfwCreateWindow( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, "CUDA-GL", NULL, NULL );

    glfwMakeContextCurrent( window );

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit( );
    glErr(); // added GL error checking

    cudaErr( cudaSetDevice( 0 ) );
    glErr(); // added GL error checking

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

    GLfloat vertices[] = {
    //   X      Y     U     V
        -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // t l
         1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // t r
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // b l

        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // b l
         1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // b r
         1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f  // t r
    };

    GLbyte pboInit[ TEX_WIDTH * TEX_HEIGHT * 4 ];
    memset( pboInit, 127, sizeof( pboInit ) );

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao );
    glBindVertexArray( vao );
    glErr(); // added GL error checking

    glGenBuffers( 1, &pbo );
    glBindBuffer( GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pbo );
    glBufferData( GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, TEX_WIDTH * TEX_HEIGHT * 4, pboInit, GL_STREAM_DRAW );
    glBindBuffer( GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0 );
    glErr(); // added GL error checking

    glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );
    glGenTextures( 1, &tex );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex );
    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, TEX_WIDTH, TEX_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glErr(); // added GL error checking

    glGenBuffers( 1, &vbo );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( vertices ), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    glErr(); // added GL error checking

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

    cudaErr( cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer( &cuGfxPBO, pbo, cudaGraphicsMapFlagsNone ) );
    glErr(); // added GL error checking

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

    vtx = glCreateShader( GL_VERTEX_SHADER );
    glShaderSource( vtx, 1, &vtxSource, NULL );
    glCompileShader( vtx );

    frg = glCreateShader( GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER );
    glShaderSource( frg, 1, &frgSource, NULL );
    glCompileShader( frg );

    shaderCompileCheck( );

    shaders = glCreateProgram( );
    glAttachShader( shaders, vtx );
    glAttachShader( shaders, frg );

    glBindFragDataLocation( shaders, 0, "outColor" );

    glLinkProgram( shaders );
    glUseProgram( shaders );

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

    GLuint posAtt = glGetAttribLocation( shaders, "position" );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( posAtt );
    glVertexAttribPointer( posAtt, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof( GLfloat ), NULL );

    GLuint texAtt = glGetAttribLocation( shaders, "texcoord" );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( texAtt );
    glVertexAttribPointer( texAtt, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof( GLfloat ), ( void* )( 2 * sizeof( GLfloat ) ) );

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

    glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );

    while( !glfwWindowShouldClose( window ) )
    {
        cudaErr( cudaGraphicsMapResources( 1, &cuGfxPBO, 0 ) );
        cudaErr( cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer( ( void** )&cudaPBOptr, &cudaPBOsize, cuGfxPBO ) );
        glErr(); // added GL error checking

        dim3 gridDim( ( int32_t )ceil( ( float )TEX_WIDTH / 16 ), ( int32_t )ceil( ( float )TEX_HEIGHT / 16 ) );
        dim3 blockDim( 16, 16 );

        makeImage<<< gridDim, blockDim >>>( cudaPBOptr, TEX_WIDTH, TEX_HEIGHT );
        cudaDeviceSynchronize( ); cudaErr( cudaGetLastError( ) );
        glErr(); // added GL error checking

        cudaErr( cudaGraphicsUnmapResources( 1, &cuGfxPBO, 0 ) );
        glErr(); // added GL error checking

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

        glBindBuffer( GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pbo );
        glErr(); // added GL error checking

        glTexSubImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, TEX_WIDTH, TEX_HEIGHT, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL );
        glErr(); // added GL error checking

        glBindBuffer( GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0 );
        glErr(); // added GL error checking

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6 );
        glErr(); // added GL error checking

        glfwSwapBuffers( window );

        glfwPollEvents( );
    }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

    glDeleteTextures( 1, &tex );

    glDeleteProgram( shaders );
    glDeleteShader( frg );
    glDeleteShader( vtx );

    glDeleteBuffers( 1, &pbo );
    glDeleteBuffers( 1, &vbo );

    glDeleteVertexArrays( 1, &vao );

    return 0;
}
```

GLdisplay.cu

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include "GLdisplay.h"

__global__ void makeImage( uint8_t* output, uint32_t width, uint32_t height )
{
    uint32_t xIdx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    uint32_t yIdx = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    uint32_t oIdx = ( xIdx + yIdx * width ) * 4;

    if( xIdx >= width || yIdx >= height ) return;

// segfault occurs if any of the lines below are commented or set to write 0
    uint8_t red = ( uint8_t )( 255.0f * ( float )( xIdx + yIdx * width ) / ( width * height ) );
    uint8_t gre = ( uint8_t )( 255.0f * ( 1.0f - ( float )( xIdx + yIdx * width ) / ( width * height ) ) );
    uint8_t blu = ( uint8_t )( 510.0f * abs( ( float )( xIdx + yIdx * width ) / ( width * height ) ) - 0.5f );

    output[ oIdx + 0 ] = red;
    output[ oIdx + 1 ] = gre;
    output[ oIdx + 2 ] = blu;
    output[ oIdx + 3 ] = 255;

 }
```

GLdisplay.h

```
#ifndef GL_DISPLAY_H
#define GL_DISPLAY_H

__global__ void makeImage( uint8_t*, uint32_t, uint32_t );

#endif
```

vert.glsl

```
#version 150

in vec2 position;
in vec2 texcoord;

out vec2 Texcoord;

void main( )
{
    Texcoord = texcoord;
    gl_Position = vec4( position, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
```

frag.glsl

```
#version 150

in vec2 Texcoord;

out vec4 outColor;

uniform sampler2D tex;

void main( )
{
    outColor = texture( tex, Texcoord );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to nvidia display driver 346.47 solved my problem completely. For the unsure, run `nvidia-smi` in a terminal window, and if you don't see `NVIDIA-SMI 346.xx` (xx being an arbitrary number), update with the newest driver available from nvidia. At the time of writing this, CUDA toolkit 6.5 ships with an outdated graphics driver.

Answer (score 0):

Your code lacks error condition checking. First and foremost I suggest you check the error code status after each and every OpenGL and CUDA call. I've got a very strong hunch what the problem is and adding the error checking will tell if this is the case.

So: I see that you never properly unbind the PBO from OpenGL before trying to map it to a CUDA pointer. Depending on the path your program takes this may result in the PBO actually not getting mapped, hence giving you an invalid pointer that if accessed, from the CUDA kernel or the host, will result in a segfault.

To pin down the problem check the error status of every OpenGL and CUDA operation. CUDA will tell you if it can't map a OpenGL resource, for whatever reason (like the resource still being bound to a OpenGL functional unit).

Comment: I'm not sure what error checking you're referencing, every one of my CUDA calls is wrapped in a routine that checks the returned cudaError_t and prints its name if cudaSuccess is not reported. I tried unbinding the PBO before any CUDA calls (and binding only for GL operations), and the same thing occurs. Before I even map the resource, my program segfaults on cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer. Again, this only happens when I change my CUDA kernel from what I have above in any way. Otherwise, I get no errors.

Comment: @briantilley: Well you're checking all the CUDA ops, but what about OpenGL? Also when you say changing the kernel, do you mean runtime change (i.e. executing a different kernel) or compile time change? BTW: If you just want to initialize a PBO, allocating it, you can just pass a null pointer. No need to allocate that pboInit array.

Comment: I mean compile time changes, as in changing the kernel to write different values to output[ oIdx + n ]. I wasn't before, but now checking openGL errors, using glGetError and glewGetErrorString, I see only "Unknown error" immediately after glewInit, but no errors for any subsequent GL or CUDA calls. The pboInit array was simply to check if CUDA was actually writing the PBO, more of a visual feedback thing.

Comment: @briantilley: that "Unknown Error" after glewInit is to be expected (it's a known issue with GLEW). Did you try running it in a debugger. Where exactly does it fail, which is the address of the attempted, faulting memory access?

Comment: ( void * ) 0x7fffff7e0038 is the faulty address given by gdb, and gdb's backtrace leads me to cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer(), which is called once during initialization. I've confirmed this by manually copy/pasting print statements.

Comment: @briantilley: Next step: Figuring out which is the segment closest by (also consider integer overflow in pointer arithmetic, that 0x7f… at the beginning looks very much like a signed integer underflow wrap). Look at /proc/$PID/maps to see what got mapped where. The interesting thing here is, that this is happening before any CUDA kernel calls have been made, so changing the kernel should not influence it; but it does so now we've to figure out what got broken.

Comment: Each time I run, the maps show vdso and vsyscall as the adjacent segments, the last two in the map, and they come right after the stack. This definitely has my head in a twist. It seems worth noting that backtrace went further to specify libcuda.so.1 for the bad memory access.

Comment: @briantilley: vdso is a shared object mapped into every process by the kernel as a helper for entering and leaving from syscalls. vsyscall provides user space implementations of "syscalls" that don't really require to change into kernel context. That something bad is happening there is a very strong indication, that your CUDA installation is broken; like that the installed kernel module doesn't really match the kernel or the version(s) of the CUDA runtime libraries. Can you check at another computer or with a different Linux installation?

Comment: I've reinstalled the entirety of cuda 6.5 and nvidia, and the problem persists on my system. Unfortunately, I don't have access to another machine or a drive to install a new OS to.

Comment: @briantilley: I'm going to check it out on my system tomorrow, try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the loads of help, I even learned a bit on the way! No need to reproduce the issue, though, it's my #$!%ing hardware. I swapped out my GTX 760 for the 560 it was meant to replace, problem gone. Might be looking at warranty services.

Comment: @briantilley: Maybe a driver update is enough to solve the problem. 340.x is not really up-to-date. Current driver release is 346.x

Comment: Funny you should say that, I just thought do so, it worked with my 760. The catch is that NVIDIA's cuda 6.5 .run installation installs 340.29 (if selected) and I had to separately install 346.47. Not a huge issue for the mildly savvy, but it's an extra step nonetheless.